# What is the expense and difficulty of moving an exterior kitchen wall?

Tags: exterior, framing, construction, remodeling, extension

I'm considering a kitchen remodel, that is in the front-right corner of a house, and surrounded by a covered deck on both sides. The deck extends out 8ft in the front and 9ft on the right.

I'd like to find out if it's possible to move the front kitchen wall into the deck area, that is basically a small alcove. The deck is original to the house, and roof line already extends to the end of the deck. So assume you don't have to move the roof line.

The length of the front wall is 13ft, and contains counter w/ sink and dishwasher. I'd like to move it out at least 3 feet, maybe the full 8ft.

How hard would this remodel be? Moving the drainage and water, electrical. Framing the new wall, building up a new subfloor, etc. Do you think this is feasible, or am I past what a contractor could pull off? What kind of cost would this be just for the extension.

Comment: Impossible to give cost estimates without knowing all the details that go into figuring these things out.

Answer (score 6):

You'd need to get an engineer to look at it first. The biggest problems I can think of are structural -- even if the house is pier and beam, you'd need to move piers out. If it's not, you would need to dig out a new foundation. Then you have to figure out if the overhang is actually appropriate as a roof over indoor space, that moving the wall won't interfere with your joist and roof structure, and make sure that you're not interfering with your attic ventilation among other things.

I wouldn't just call a contractor and have him start swinging a hammer, and I definitely wouldn't do this yourself. On top of that, this will definitely require a lot of permits and a stamped architectural design to be filed with your city or county.

Comment: anyway to ballpark the cost? 10k,20k,30k?

Comment: Not without seeing how your house is constructed, and even then it's variable depending on area. Plan on $2k-$3k to get started with an Architect, and then I'd shoot for the high side ($30k) of the span you indicated. You're basically building an addition, albeit a small one, and you have all the sunk costs of such an endeavor.

Answer (score 3):

I would love to see a pic of the deck and roof coverage.  Any time you expand the footprint of a house, then permits will be required. In some areas, you may need an engineer stamp on some plans, but in most areas a simple floor plan and a competent building contractor will be what you need.  Again, depending on where you live, the price per square foot is going to vary widely. In my area, for example, a simple addition runs between $95 and $160 per square foot. You will be looking at foundation, framing, wiring, windows/doors and possibility mating to your existing roof or replacing it.  It is not a complicated job for a pro, but daunting for a DIYer with little experience.  Get a few quotes and check references. Go see some of the work the bidding contractors have done and chat with the customers. Satisfied customers love to show off their completed projects.  Never, and I mean NEVER, be swayed by a cheap price. Do a complete scope of work and have a written contract describing EXACTLY what is to be done, right down to the brand of paint and who cleans up on the last day!   Good luck, sounds exciting.